# How to use xml with android application?

Tags: android, xml

I am currently creating my first android application
i never used it before

What i need is to read xml file from the internet and put it in a list

( to read this xml http://pollsdb.com/test.txt and put the results in list )

i will appreciate if someone can post a code that works

Answer (score 0):

XML Pull Parser is an interface that defines parsing functionality provided in XMLPULL V1 API .

There are following different kinds of parser depending on which features are set:

non-validating parser as defined in XML 1.0 spec when FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL is set to true
validating parser as defined in XML 1.0 spec when FEATURE_VALIDATION is true (and that implies that FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL is true)
when FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL is false (this is default and if different value is required necessary must be changed before parsing is started) then parser behaves like XML 1.0 compliant non-validating parser under condition that no DOCDECL is present in XML documents (internal entites can still be defined with defineEntityReplacementText()). This mode of operation is intended for operation in constrained environments such as J2ME.
There are two key methods: next() and nextToken(). While next() provides access to high level parsing events, nextToken() allows access to lower level tokens.

The current event state of the parser can be determined by calling the getEventType() method. Initially, the parser is in the START_DOCUMENT state.

The method next() advances the parser to the next event. The int value returned from next determines the current parser state and is identical to the value returned from following calls to getEventType ().

Th following event types are seen by next()

START_TAG
An XML start tag was read.
TEXT
Text content was read; the text content can be retrieved using the getText() method. (when in validating mode next() will not report ignorable whitespace, use nextToken() instead)
END_TAG
An end tag was read
END_DOCUMENT
No more events are available
after first next() or nextToken() (or any other next*() method) is called user application can obtain XML version, standalone and encoding from XML declaration in following ways:

version: getProperty("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#xmldecl-version") returns String ("1.0") or null if XMLDecl was not read or if property is not supported
standalone: getProperty("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#xmldecl-standalone") returns Boolean: null if there was no standalone declaration or if property is not supported otherwise returns Boolean(true) if standalone="yes" and Boolean(false) when standalone="no"
encoding: obtained from getInputEncoding() null if stream had unknown encoding (not set in setInputStream) and it was not declared in XMLDecl

A minimal example for using this API may look as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.StringReader;

 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
 import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

 public class SimpleXmlPullApp
 {

     public static void main (String args[])
         throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
     {
         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
         System.out.println("End document");
     }
 }
```

The above example will generate the following output:

```
Start document
 Start tag foo
 Text Hello World!
 End tag foo
```

EDIT THE CODE TO YOUR NEEDS  :)

Comment: but how to get the xml text from an external website?